# find the upper and lower bound for a finite sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, upper-lower-bounds

Find upper and lower bound for the following finite sum

$1/(1 + 1^3)+1/(1 +2^3)+1/(1 + 3^3) + ··· + 1/(1 + n^3)$

My attempt:

$1/(1 + 1^3)+1/(1 +2^3)+1/(1 + 3^3) + ··· + 1/(1 + n^3)$ = $\sum_{i=1}^n 1/(1+i^3)$ = $\int_1^n$1/$(1+i^3)$di = $\int_1^n1/(1+x^3)$dx

But now I'm stuck.Is my attempt correct?

Comment: It'a not correct. You can't substitute sum with an integral

Answer (score 1):

No, because$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{1+i^3}\not=\int_1^n\frac1{1+x^3}\,\mathrm dx.$$However,$$\int_i^{i+1}\frac1{1+x^3}\,\mathrm dx\leqslant\frac1{1+i^3}\leqslant\int_{i-1}^i\frac1{1+x^3}\,\mathrm dx,$$and you can use this to solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: How can I find upper and lower bounds using this. I don't get it

Comment: $$\int_0^n\frac1{1+x^3}\,\mathrm dx\leqslant\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{1+i^3}\leqslant\int_1^{n+1}\frac1{1+x^3}\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: so the lower bound is $\int_0^n {1/1+x^3}$ and the upper one is $\int_1^{n+1} {1/1+x^3}$ ?

Comment: At least, those are the lower bounds that I got.

Comment: Which ones are the loower bounds? I'm losttt

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: My question is: how can I find upper and lower bound for the above finite sum?

Comment: By computing those integrals.

Comment: one of those integrals is the lower and the other is the upper?

Comment: Yes, that is what I wrote.

Comment: @dodobc I added the standard diagram (drawn by hand) for this.