# Upper and Lower bound of a finite sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, upper-lower-bounds

Find upper and lower bound for the following finite sum:

$$\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{3^3} + ··· + \frac{1}{n^3} $$

My attempt is:

Using the integral test:

we know that  $\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{3^3} + ··· + \frac{1}{n^3}$ = $$\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i^3 = \int_1^n1/i^3di = \int_1^n1/x^3dx = -1/2n^2 + 1/2$$

But now I'm stuck. How can this give the lower and upper bouunds?

Comment: [Why make new accounts for the same thing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3115150/find-the-upper-and-lower-bound-for-a-finite-sum) ?

Comment: How about learning Fourier analysis to calculate its exact value in terms of $\pi$?

Comment: we didnt learn Fourier analysis yet